# Sequelize migration problem and npm start problem, they dont run

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

The problem i have is clear in the attachement below, i ran sequelize db:migrate and it blocks without doing anything. I ran npm start && sequelize db:migrate and it blocked at npm start. anyone been through this?
at first i thought it was a node version problem I was using 14.17.2 I eventually downgraded to 13.13.0 but I still have the same problem, my project is due in 3 days and i'm stuck here.

attachement below: [my console's pov](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep8P0.png)

```
{
  "name": "immobis-rest-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "~2.6.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "node": "^16.4.0",
    "pg": "^8.0.3",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
    "pg-promise": "^10.10.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.4",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0",
    "snyk": "^1.653.0"
  }
}
```

and heres my config file

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "root123",
    "database": "Immobis",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "dialectOptions": {
      "ssl": true
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "root123",
    "database": "Immobis",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "dialectOptions": {
      "ssl": true
    }
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "root123",
    "database": "Immobis",
    "host": "localhost",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "dialectOptions": {
      "ssl": true
    }
  }
}
```

edit: I found out that I just didnt console.log for the npm start problem, nvm that please, thank you.

Comment: hi! please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Improving your question with a minimum running example will help a lot.
Also, what error are you getting? what have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, but the console just stops outputting anything, I waited for a while until I finally ctrl+c out of it you can see the image in the link, you'll see that I get no errors

Comment: could you run the migration in debug/verbose mode?
also, what happens if you try to connect to the database from console?
finally, please add the migrations you want to run to the question.

Comment: through the console the database connects normally, the fact that sequelize add plural "s" to table names played me, I removed the "s" in pgadmin, even thought it's not optimal but it works now, thank you @germanio for your time, I wish you never have an error in your code my friend

Comment: good to hear it's solved now, have a good week!